# Fingerprint enroll-data-full KDE Plasma 5.24 thinkpad p1 gen 4

Tags: kde, plasma, fingerprint

I've upgraded to KDE Plasma 5.24 and I have installed frpintd successfully. It even shows up under Users as GUI. Yet as I start setting up the finger print... the result is this

[image]

Enroll-data-full . How can I fix this? On a previous installation i had fngerprint working flawlessly...

Comment: Stack overflow is for problems related to programming only. I'm not trying to be mean, but people on this site are generally super strict and you're probably about to get downvoted to death so be prepared :(. I'd post this on https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-forums-50/

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the storage for fingerprints (usually stored on the fingerprint-reader itself) is full.
In your BIOS under the tab "Security" there is an item "Fingerprint Reader". Open it and select the option to clear fingerprint storage. This will delete any fingerprints stored on the chip. Afterwards you can enroll new fingerprints again.